# Remove [subjective]

Tags: support, tags, tag-block-request, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please can we destroy the subjective tag?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1008/please-can-we-destroy-the-subjective-tag)

The [[subjective]](https://askubuntu.com/tags/subjective) tag should be removed and blacklisted from Ask Ubuntu for the same reasons it was [removed from other sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

For past discussion, see [SO.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51627/54262).

Comment: Forward closed as user is no longer active.