# Please can we destroy the subjective tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-block-request

The [subjective](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/subjective) tag has 12 questions. Please can it be blacklisted per [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: Probably a good idea, since it means either either "Community Wiki" or [closed] .

Answer (score 6):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]