# Why do we have a "help" tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-block-request

[help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/help) is kind of a pointless tag, no?  There's 36 questions which have it, each of them is asking for support with something different.  There's no real purpose for it, since this site is for support and help *anyways*.  Should it be removed?

Comment: +1 Yes, it should go.

Comment: Editing all those questions as we speak. [tag:help] should be eradicated anywhere it occurs, IMO.

Comment: Why isn't the Help tag gone yet? it's as pointless as having a Ubuntu tag....

Comment: Agreed, i guess nobody's bothered to blacklist it.

Comment: It was created yesterday *again*.

Answer (score 11):

[help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/help) is one of those "meta" tags that seriously needs to go. It could apply to a vast majority of the questions on Ask Ubuntu and serves no constructive purpose. It should be killed with fire.

Comment: I like the "It should be killed by fire" part.  :P

Comment: But, but, but - how will I know which people actually need help and which ones are pretending?

Comment: Hmm, speaking of killing it with fire, could we have it [burninated](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1555/18612)?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Why not just pretend all of them need help? That approach might help with our huge backlog of unanswered questions, actually.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I was being sarcastic :)