# Please blacklist the help tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-block-request

Please blacklist the tag [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/help), its a useless meta tag that can contain literally *any question*.  It should be purged with fire.

---

Related:  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2179/why-do-we-have-a-help-tag

> It was created yesterday again. – Emerson Hsieh [15 hours ago](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2179/why-do-we-have-a-help-tag#comment5511_2179)

Comment: I just removed 3 questions that used that tag.  Its a meta tag, and gets used too often.  We purged that tag a while ago from questions, but its been recreated.

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, the tag should be blacklisted.

I cannot see any useful use of the tag, so I propose that:

- Community members go through the tag page and replace tags on posts with more useful and descriptive tags.
- The help tag is blacklisted so it cannot be used.

Notes:

- While [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/help) can refer to documentation, [yelp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/yelp) is better.
- The [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/help) tag was [blacklisted on StackOverflow for the same reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102165/please-blacklist-the-help-tag). As Jeff Atwood said, "if we removed it and it keeps coming back, that's a fair argument for blacklist." The [help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/help) tag situation here on AU [seems to have developed into the same](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3706/please-blacklist-the-help-tag#comment5516_3706), so it should be blacklisted here as well.

Comment: [tag:help] has now been blacklisted.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks much.

Answer (score -2):

## No! Do not blacklist the tag!

I think the tag is useful and should not be blacklisted.

<sub>Please edit this and include any reasoning behind your thoughts.</sub>